# Como adaptar um app em Android a diversos tamanhos de tela?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Por exemplo...
Quero o app em Android seja apresentado igualmente tanto em telas de 5" à 3"...
E como faço para aplicar um layout de "rolagem", como adiiconar um scroll ao layout em Android?

Comment: E tipo assim... Estou rodando o app em um aparelho com uma tela de 5", e na minha activity tenho certos elementos com um valor de marginTop... E quando vou rodar essa mesma activity em um aparelho de 3" ele acaba ultrapassando os limites da tela... Tem como definir uma activity específica para aparelhos com esse determinado tamanho de  tela?

Answer (score 3):

Use `wrap_content` e `match_parent`:

Para garantir que o seu layout seja flexível e se adapte a diferentes tamanhos de tela, você deve usar "wrap_content" e "match_parent" para a largura e altura de alguns componentes de visualização. Se você usar "wrap_content" , a largura ou a altura da view ficará definida para o tamanho mínimo necessário para se auto ajustar ao conteúdo que está dentro, enquanto "match_parent" (também conhecido como "fill_parent" anterior à API 8) faz com que o componente se expanda para corresponder ao tamanho da view(parent ou pai).

Exemplo do uso de "wrap_content" e "match_parent":

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"  
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_height="50dp">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/logo"
                   android:paddingRight="30dp"
                   android:layout_gravity="left"
                   android:layout_weight="0" />
        <View android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/view1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/categorybutton"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                style="@style/CategoryButtonStyle"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/headlines" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:name="com.example.android.newsreader.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Leia mais...](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseWrapMatchPar)

Comment: Ótima resposta, mas não seria legal falar do  "match_constraint" também?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que na maioria dos casos declarar os elementos do XML utilizando `wrap_content` e `match_parent` funciona bem.

Porém, para comportar diferentes situações com maior liberdade, o Android permite a declaração de elementos com base no tamanho da tela, densidade e orientação. Isso com certeza pode fazer toda a diferença.

Para utilizar vários arquivos diferentes, basta declará-los com um identificador.
Por exemplo:
se você declarar `res/layout/main_activity.xml` esse recurso será o padrão, porém ao incluir o arquivo `res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml`, o sistema carregará este layout caso a menor largura (smallest width) seja de 600dp.

Esse princípio se mantem para qualquer outro qualificador, como por exemplo `res/layout-land/main_activity.xml` que será carregado caso o aparelho esteja em modo paisagem.

Uma lista com os qualificadores pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).